# How to modify rank of a bug pattern in FindBugs (Eclipse plugin)

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs

I'm using the FindBugs eclipse plugin for static analysis and also Sonar.
my problem is that category level of findbugs and sonar isn't same.
findbugs reports bug pattern by rank value (scariest, scary, troubling, of concern)
but sonar reports bug pattern by severity (blocker, critical, major, minor, info)

I really want to match these category in a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use the [SonarQube Eclipse plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse), this will bring you the following advantages:

- no need to match whatever category: what you have in Eclipse is the same concept as what you see on the SonarQube server
- you'll also get many other violations/issues, reported by SonarQube itself, Checkstyle or PMD